# Saving file in php

Tags: php, curl

I have a variable: $Name = "name of the file".
Now I download a file and store in it with that name and its extension. I used cURL.

```
$Name = "name of the file"
$fp = fopen ('download/$Name.zip' , 'w+'); 
$ch = curl_init($downurl);
```

But this didn't work. It saved a file named $Name.zip
I want it to be saved as "name of the file.zip" in download folder.

I am learning php. Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that you're using single-quotes. Variable values aren't interpolated / expanded when they're in single-quotes. **Use double-quotes instead**: `fopen ("download/$Name.zip" , 'w+');`

Comment: Yes it is PHP, and @AmalMurali is correct. Use double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Use double quotes in the `fopen` call:

```
$fp = fopen ("download/$Name.zip" , 'w+');
```

Interpolation of variables doesn't work if you surround the string in single quotes, it has to be double quotes. You can read more about [variable interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_interpolation) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Yeah. My bad. And do you know how to echo the url of that downloaded file?

Comment: It is also described under [Strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing): "*When a string is specified in double quotes or with heredoc, variables are parsed within it.*"

Comment: Do you want to echo `$downurl`? Because that's simply `echo $downurl;`, if you want to echo the URL of the newly downloaded file on your web server that's outside the scope of this question and should be put in a new question.

Comment: I meant the url of that downloaded file so that other can download it from my server. Like a leecher.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$fp = fopen ('download/$Name.zip' , 'w+');
```

to

```
$fp = fopen ("download/$Name".".zip" , 'w+');
```

you'll also need to set some header info if you wish to output the file rather than just dump its contents

```
  Header("Content-type: archive/zip");
  Header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download.zip");
```